# Is the Amazon credit card reported to the credit agencies?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit-report

Is the Amazon Store credit card reported to the credit agencies?

I'd like to know if a good payment history with this card will affect credit score or not.

Comment: Are you talking about the Amazon.com Rewards Visa Card, or the Amazon Store Card?

Comment: Store Card. I know the rewards card will report.

Comment: I see others actually looked it up. But I'd say in general, store cards do indeed show up on your credit report. I have a couple of store cards and they all show up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Amazon.com Store Card Terms and Conditions](https://www.onlinecreditcenter6.com/consumereApply/Internet/amazon/en/js/TermsConditions.htm) state the following:

> **Credit Bureau Reporting.** We may report information about your account to credit bureaus. Late payments, missed payments, or other defaults on your account may be shown in your credit report.

The card is issued by Synchrony Bank. Generally, store cards *do* report to credit bureaus, so I see no reason why this one would not.

[image: Amazon.com Store Card]

Comment: Curious. You show a different bank. Yet, both sites show a fresh date.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Our answers are about two different cards. My answer is about the card he asked about (Amazon store card), and your answer is about the Amazon rewards Visa card, which he said in the comments he was not asking about.

Comment: I can confirm that my Amazon Store Card does show up as Synchrony Bank, like Ben mentioned. It also correctly identifies my credit limit and utilization as one would expect. I've had it for years, even before they switched to Synchrony.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The [T&C page](https://creditcards.chase.com/credit-cards/amazon-credit-card.aspx) shows:

> Authorization: When you respond to this credit card offer from Chase
>   Bank USA, N.A., a subsidiary of JPMorgan Chase & Co. ("Chase", "we",
>   or "us"), you agree to the following:

Which means a real bank is behind the card. Yes. It will hit your credit report.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted for the details on the bank in question and confirmation of reporting on Rewards card.

Comment: Funny. My reply was timestamped 4 minutes before OP clarified 'store card'. But the DV still followed....

Comment: Mine shows up on my credit report.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Still appreciate the response, hence the upvote. :) Ben's just happened to be more specific to what I was looking for.